# How to implement specialized versions of a generic function?

Tags: rust, traits, specialization, generic-function

I'd like to have multiple versions of a function optimized for type of its arguments, and Rust call appropriate one depending on context.

In my case all arguments have the same type, and all are equivalent, so it'd rather avoid having a `self` argument.

I've [tried this code](http://is.gd/hzjtrp):

```
trait Foo<T> { 
    fn foo(a: T, b: T, c: T); 
}

impl Foo<i32> {
    fn foo(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) {}
}

impl Foo<i16> {
    fn foo(a: i16, b: i16, c: i16) {}
}

fn main() {
    Foo::foo(1i32,2,3);
    Foo::foo(1i16,2,3);
}
```

but Rust requires type annotations:

> error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_ : Foo<i32>` [E0283]

Can I avoid providing type annotations at the call site? If I have to, how to do it?

Comment: Any current specialisation of a generic function is a quirk that probably isn't actually meant to work (i.e. it's a bug). [True specialisation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) is a proposed but not implemented feature.

Comment: @huon: Shouldn't that be an answer, as temporary as it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that you *always* implement a trait **for** something. Therefore, trait implementation must *always* contain `for` clause:

```
impl SomeTrait for Something
```

If there is no `for`, then it is not a trait implementation. In your case `impl Foo<i32>` is not an implementation of `Foo` for `i32` or whatever you think it is; it is an *inherent* method declaration clause on the *bare trait object type* `Foo<i32>`.

What you actually want is possible to do using `Self` type parameter:

```
trait Foo { 
    fn foo(a: Self, b: Self, c: Self); 
}

impl Foo for i32 {
    fn foo(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) {}
}

impl Foo for i16 {
    fn foo(a: i16, b: i16, c: i16) {}
}

fn main() {
    Foo::foo(1i32,2,3);
    Foo::foo(1i16,2,3);
}
```

This code [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9ab30d20d5c6d3a06bf4&version=stable).

Note that now `Foo` is implemented **for** a certain type. The type a trait is implemented for is available via the implicit `Self` type parameter, and you can see how it is used in `foo()` declaration.